# Calculating the coefficient of $x^k$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, generating-functions

> In order to calculate the coefficient of $x^k$ in the sum $$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac {\big(-(\frac {x}{1!}+\frac {x^2}{2!}+\cdots )\big)^n}{n}=\frac {-1}{1}\big(\frac {x}{1!}+\frac {x^2}{2!}+\cdots \big)+\frac {(-1)^2}{2}\big(\frac {x}{1!}+\frac {x^2}{2!}+\cdots \big)^2+\cdots +\frac {(-1)^n}{n}\big(\frac {x}{1!}+\frac {x^2}{2!}+\cdots \big)^n+\cdots $$
>   , we just need to find the coefficient of $x^k$ in
>   $$\frac {(-1)^n}{n}\big(\frac {x}{1!}+\frac {x^2}{2!}+\cdots \big)^n \quad , \text {when} \quad n\leq k$$
>
> So, $$\sum_{1b_1+2b_2+\cdots +(k-n)(b_{k-n})=k} \binom {n}{b_1}x^{b_1\cdot 1}\binom {n-b_1}{b_2}\dfrac {(x)^{b_2\cdot 2}}{(2!)^{b_2}}\binom {n-b_1-b_2}{b_3}\dfrac {(x)^{b_3\cdot 3}}{(3!)^{b_3}}\cdots n \dfrac {x^{\big(k-n\big)\big(b_{k-n}\big)}}{\big(k-n\big)!} \tag {*}$$

These are in my lecture notes, and I didn't understand the starred part. How is that obtained?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)? This is a direct use of it.

Comment: It's according to the multinomial thm done this way as I see: $$(x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots )^n=\sum \binom{n}{b_1,b_2,\cdots ,b_{k-n}}\big(x \big)^{b_1}\big(\frac{x^2}{2!} \big)^{b_2}\cdots \big(\frac{x^{k-n}}{(k-n)!} \big)^{b_{k-n}}$$
The thing that I didnt understand is why it goes from $x$ to $x^{k-n}$ Does this sum cover all the term in $(x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots )^n$? @PrasunBiswas

Comment: It looks to me like $k-n$ is supposed to be the *largest possible index contribution* to $x^k$. However, I think that should be $k-n+1$ which happens when we get a contribution of $x^1/1!$ from $n-1$ of the factors and $k-n+1$ from the remaining factor.

Comment: Could you write it explicitly?@N.Shales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe we have
\begin{align}
\left(\sum^\infty_{i=1} \frac{x^i}{i!} \right)^n = \underbrace{\left(\sum^\infty_{i_1=1} \frac{x^{i_1}}{i_1!} \right)\cdots \left(\sum^\infty_{i_n=1} \frac{x^{i_n}}{i_n!} \right)}_{n-\text{times}}
\end{align}
which we would like to rewrite in the form
\begin{align}
\left(\sum^\infty_{i_1=1} \frac{x^{i_1}}{i_1!} \right)\cdots \left(\sum^\infty_{i_n=1} \frac{x^{i_n}}{i_n!} \right)=\sum^\infty_{k=n} c_k x^k.
\end{align}
Naively, it's clear that
\begin{align}
\left(\sum^\infty_{i_1=1} \frac{x^{i_1}}{i_1!} \right)\cdots \left(\sum^\infty_{i_n=1} \frac{x^{i_n}}{i_n!} \right) = \sum^\infty_{k=n}\left(\sum_{i_1+\ldots + i_n=k}\frac{1}{i_1!\ldots i_n!} \right)x^k.
\end{align}
However, we would like to use a more combinatorical argument to rewrite the coefficient.

First, fix some $k\geq n$.

Viewing each $\left(\sum^\infty_{i_j=1} \frac{x^{i_j}}{i_j!} \right)$ as a "basket" we see that the maximum term which we can consider is $x^{k-n+1}$ from this basket. For instance, as remarked by @N.Shales, if I consider $i_1 = k-n+1$, then $i_2=\cdots=i_n = 1$. This little observation allows us to truncate each summation so we can consider
\begin{align}
\left(\sum^{k-n+1}_{i_1=1} \frac{x^{i_1}}{i_1!} \right)\cdots \left(\sum^{k-n+1}_{i_n=1} \frac{x^{i_n}}{i_n!} \right). \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\ast)
\end{align}

Let us note that we only care about the coefficient of $x^k$ from $\ (\ast)$, but this amounts to finding the number of ways of choosing $b_1\geq 1$ numbers of $x^1$ from $n$ baskets, number of ways of choosing $b_2\geq 2$ numbers of $x^2/2!$ from $n$ baskets, etc, so that
\begin{align}
b_1+ b_2 \ldots + b_{k-n+1} = n\\
1\cdot b_1 + 2\cdot b_2 + \ldots + (k-n+1)\cdot b_{k-n+1} =k
\end{align} 
This is precisely given by
\begin{align}
&\sum_{1\cdot b_1 +\ldots + (k-n+1)\cdot b_{k-n+1}=k} \binom{n}{b_1}\underbrace{x^1\cdots x^1}_{b_1-\text{times}} \binom{n-b_1}{b_2}\underbrace{\frac{x^{2}}{2!}\cdots \frac{x^{2}}{2!}}_{b_2-\text{times}}\cdots \binom{n-b_1-\ldots-b_{k-n}}{b_{k-n+1}}\underbrace{\frac{x^{k-n+1}}{(k-n+1)!}\cdots \frac{x^{k-n+1}}{(k-n+1)!}}_{b_{k-n+1}-\text{times}}\\
=&\ \sum_{1\cdot b_1 +\ldots + (k-n+1)\cdot b_{k-n+1}=k} \binom{n}{b_1}x^{1\cdot b_1}\binom{n-b_1}{b_2}\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2!}\right)^{b_2}\cdots \binom{n-b_1-\ldots-b_{k-n}}{b_{k-n+1}}\left(\frac{x^{k-n+1}}{(k-n+1)!}\right)^{b_{k-n+1}}.
\end{align}

Comment: It now makes a lot sense. Thanks for this great answer. However, I only have an issue with the idea of "$x^{k−n+1}$ being the maximum term from this basket" I can't see why it is the maximum.

Comment: Great work Jacky, very clear. @LeylaAlkan, sorry I didn't get back sooner. Anyway, it might help is you use an example, say $n=4$ and $k=8$. Then $(x^1/1!+x^2/2!\cdots)^4$ and the "biggest" contributor to $x^8$ from the factors is $x^5$ because we have $3$ contributions of $x^1$ and thus $8-3=5$ is the greatest power of $x$ that can go with these. Look back at the variables and you'll see that $5=8-(4-1)1$ or $5=k-(n-1)1=k-n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By using the Taylor expansion of the exponential function you can rewrite the first sum as:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(1-\exp(x))^n}{n}.$$

Compare this to the Taylor series of

$$-\ln(1-u)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{u^n}{n},$$

which is valid if $|u|<1$.

Hence we obtain for $u=1-\exp(x)$ for $|1-\exp(x)|<1$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(1-\exp(x))^n}{n}=-\ln\left(1-(1-\exp(x))\right)=x.$$

Comment: Yes, I get this part but I didn't understand how the starred part is done

Comment: This is an alternative solution. I also do not understand your lecture notes.

Comment: Tell me that :)

Comment: @LeylaAlkan: I think the sum in your proposed problem should have limits $r=1$ to $n$ and we would investigate the coefficient of $x^r$, because otherwise, the sum as explicitly stated, evaluates to $x$ which has coefficient $1$ when $k=1$ and $0$ otherwise. The alternate version which I think is the actual aim of your lecture notes can be done by just applying multinomial theorem (though the expression for the coefficient would be quite cumbersome).